# Should Wad Cheber be added to the room owners of Mos Eisley permanently?

Tags: discussion, chat

WadCheber has been added temporarily to the room owners of Mos Eisley [by Slytherincess](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=29746092#29746092), as she needs backup while she moves to a new house.

> Everyone, please welcome @WadCheber as a temporary Room Owner of Mos Eisley! Wad has been kind enough to be a backup of sorts for me while I move to a new house. Wad will be an RO until July 1st. Thank you, Wad! :D
>
> *— Slytherincess*

To increase the number of non-mod room owners, should we make this permanent (if Wad Cheber is willing, of course)?

Comment: I appreciate the support, but I don't know if we need to do this.

Comment: What can a room owner do that a non-room owner can't?

Comment: @PeterPeter : Plenty.  They can remove pin / unpin items, remove stars, and kick-mute (temporarily silence) a user, for instance.  (Source: I'm a room owner.)

Comment: @PeterPeter Some back info here: [Should Mos Eisley have non-moderator owners, and if so, who?](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/q/7240/21267)

Comment: @PeterPeter The full answer to that is [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/271269/278659).

Comment: It's interesting finding these types of questions. Seeing as I don't really spend time in chat, I'm out of touch with a lot of the culture (and drama) that surrounds this community. Then all sorts of random meta questions show up that indicate stuff is afoot with *really* vague details.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### No, at least not at the moment.

Because reasons.

Comment: I upvoted this. Mostly for comedy value.

Comment: I downvoted this for pragmatic and honest reasons.

Comment: I accepted this because WadChaber has of course the final say in this. I asked this without consulting him first, which was wrong. My apologies.

Answer (score -1):

**Yes**

This is a good idea. Wad has shown great commitment to the Stack and to Mos Eisley. He is the embodiment of "be nice". He should be a permanent room owner.

---

*This should not preclude other committed regular users from becoming additional room owners, of course.*