# Looking for a third room owner for (Mos Eisley) our chat room (Update: Found!)

Tags: discussion, chat

### Update

**Please welcome our newest room owners: [Gallifreyan](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/228525/gallifreyan), [Ixrec](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/137186/ixrec), and [KutuluMike](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/55089/kutulumike)! Multiple room owners have been chosen based on the close scores between the top three nominations as of 4/21/17.**

---

We are looking for a third room owner for Mos Eisley, SFF's chat room. Praxis has been insanely busy and Slytherincess has had some health stuff going on, and there have been times Mos Eisley has been a bit neglected < pat pat, poor boo! >.

[Expectations for being a room owner](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269) are very manageable and shouldn't take up much of an owner's time.

My experience has been very positive. I've never been meant to feel unwelcome or awkward because I'm a room owner. I've not had to kick anyone from chat, although I've had to take a few comments to the trash can. Every time there has been a tense conversation going on, the instigator has eventually responded to verbal redirection and chat has been able to resume and move along without putting the room into time out. I really encourage you to nominate yourself or another chat member to be our third room owner -- c'mon!

Again, here is the [guide to moderating chat](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/271267/a-guide-to-moderating-chat/271269#271269) that you can refer to, that outlines the duties of the chat room owner.

- **Yes, you may nominate yourself.**
- **Yes, you may nominate another user.**

If you are nominated by another user and are ***not*** interested in taking the position, simply leave a comment declining the nomination.

Please let the community know why you feel you would be suitable for the position. Do you have prior moderation experience? Tell us about it!

**Are you a regular chatter?**

This is actually meant to be a casual election -- this is certainly not at the level of the diamond moderator. We just want to know a little about you and why you would enjoy being one of Mos Eisley's room owners. :)

### Please nominate!

Comment: So you need a moderator for a wretched hive of scum and villany?

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To Mos is cool now, they only discuss politics every day :)

Comment: @Praxis and Sly: Since ROs and Moderators can appoint whomever they wish, I have a couple questions: Are you merely taking votes into consideration, or are you going by a "winner" of votes? Is there a reason for just one room owner? We're one of the more active chats on the network, and some rooms have many ROs, not just 2-3. There's two candidates now that have strong support. One has been around for awhile and is familiar with the history of chat & knows the ropes,  and one is newer blood that shows signs of being around for awhile & already cares about the quality of the chat. Why not both?

Comment: @CreationEdge *"And the doctoral student gets to co-author a paper with an undergraduate - everyone is happy!"* - from somewhere on [Academia.se]

Comment: @can-ned_food All the SFF mods are also room owners of Mos, just by virtue of being SFF mods (it's mainly symbolic, since we'd all have RO powers anyway). By "third room owner" Slytherincess means a third specially appointed non-mod room owner. These are chosen specifically for their *chat* moderation abilities, unlike site mods, and are generally appointed after [polls on meta](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7240/31394) like this one.

Comment: @CreationEdge - Let me see if I can answer your questions. ROs can't just appoint a new RO. It's brought to the community and typically the person or persons with the most votes are then vetted by the mods and CMs for final approval. I don't think there is a reason for the number of ROs -- maybe Rand could say? I'm certainly not opposed to electing more than one RO. I think Mos would do well with more ROs than less, tbh. So, if the community, mods, ROs, and CMs want more ROs, I have absolutely no problem with that. In fact, I would welcome the support! :)

Comment: @All, echoing Slytherincess: ROs are appointed by existing ROs/mods/CMs on the *advice* of community votes; the results of this meta thread aren't binding. (I've [checked](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/24195312#24195312) and this is how it was done last time.) So **worrying about other people's motivations for voting is a red herring**. Cast your own votes, discuss the merits or demerits of the candidates, and may the best user(s) win!

Comment: Is there a cutoff date?

Comment: @Valorum No, we're waiting for the voting to stabilize.

Comment: My gripe is always the "answers" have 40+ votes, yet the question only has 20.....

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I did not know that ROs appoint new ROs. In that case, I'm willing to bet people would be surprised at who I would appoint, given the power! Heh!  :)

Comment: @Slytherincess Just out of curiosity.... is that person on the list below already, or do we some more nominees?  ;-)

Comment: @Skooba --  Some of the *people* I would pick (or would have) have been nominated; some have not. :)

Answer (score 20):

I nominate [Gallifreyan](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/70236/gallifreyan). He seems pretty level-headed, is in the room regularly and I've not seen him get involved in any drama.

[image]

---

Gallifreyan here: I would be happy and honoured to help keep our wretched hive of scum and villainy cozy and warm!

I'm [around](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09se7.png) almost at the same time Mos has most messages [posted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzZKf.png) (I live in GMT +3), so I can [see](https://media1.giphy.com/media/f3Fq267SERQm4/giphy.gif) almost everything and react promptly. I don't usually post much unless asked, but I'm constantly hovering around (benefits of a laptop and university Wi-Fi). Leaving a ping will always [draw me out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8kTc.jpg).

Comment: I'll add my support also.

Comment: @Mithrandir AND MY AXE!

Comment: @CandiedMango -- Uh ... and second breakfast?

Comment: I support this nomination 100%.

Comment: @CandiedMango and my bow(?)

Comment: But yes 100% agree. A very friendly and welcoming chap whose around a lot and always there to help. Sometimes feels a bit like a miniature Rand (if rep count determined size)

Comment: @Edlothiad I guess you can give him your bow but I now mostly want the second breakfasts

Comment: Good suggestion!

Comment: @CandiedMango [*Tosses apple over head*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkzvHtjnNOs)

Comment: What arguments against Gallifreyan are there? He's on more than Mike, he's a nice guy, he's never been in a fight with anyone.  Why the -9?

Comment: @Terriblefan - MissMoniceE has a similar (in fact identical) number of downvotes.

Comment: @Valorum This does not bode well.

Comment: @Terriblefan - What's weird is that they all came in a very short space. He went from +18 to +12 in a day. MissMonicaE went from +10 to +1

Comment: @Valorum I noticed that too, but I thought I was making more of it than I ought.  Well, if Mike's friends want to see Mike as room owner enough to downvote everyone else, then maybe they should adopts a slogan:  _I Like Mike_

Answer (score 16):

I nominate [KutuluMike](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/2816/kutulumike).

[image]

He is a well-respected user and in my experience has always shown good judgment.  I am confident that he would treat others fairly along with being helpful as I have witnessed him do in the past.

KutuluMike is always in the chat room whenever I am around, which is on a daily basis (mostly).  He appears to be available at times when mods or other room owners are not.  I have also pinged him when he is not in the room and he becomes available very quickly.

He has also been a member of the community for over 5 years, which makes him knowledgeable about how the chat room works as well as the sci-fi community here.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChIStIzQqnI

Comment: Okay, are there any concerns the downvoters would like to share?

Comment: I find the recent turn surprising. I haven't been in Mos in over a year, but in all the years I was in there, Mike was one of the most level-headed users around. Always helpful to new users, quick to try to defuse volatile situations, and generally did a lot to help grow and keep the chat fun with things like his bot, Joshua. Did this all change while I've been away?

Comment: @phantom42 - Some down-votes are from people he antagonized directly (prior to what he did to me in 2016 in chat, i'd have up-voted as I agreed with your assessment. Now I DVed. So I'm petty, sue me). Some may be from people turned off by some of what went on on AoN - not everyone's enamored of politicized cliques; and unfortunately for Mike he clearly chose to associate himself with one.   Some are from people who may be unhappy with mass-down-votes on competing answers (and what those DVs say about the previous point). Ironically, your sarcasm had a point - some of it was "while ... away"

Comment: @Gallifreyan - yes. I'm concerned about Mike's attitude about the recent flags in chat. He seems to believe that nothing should be flagged. He also concerned me with his message 'chat flags mean lurking in transcript waiting to flag Himarm'. I believe that that showed a slight problem.

Comment: What is this?  Pick on Mike day?  The whole thing about Mike making the comment about "waiting to flag Himarm" is just harmless jokes.  Ever since I have been around Mos, most people make harmless jokes all of the time. That's why I like chatting in Mos, because it's a fun atmosphere.  I would rather have a RO that has a sense of humor with a more laid back approach than someone with a dictator type attitude.

Comment: @amaranth I think if "*Gallifreyan's clique*" had mass down-voted, they'd have done it as soon as their "*front-runner*" was mass-downvoted into second place. Whereas the supposed accusation on Mike's clique down voting came just as he was nominated.

Comment: <comments about Mithrandir's moderation removed> Please, keep the discussion constructive and relevant to the nominees here.

Comment: @DVK-on-Ahch-To This was getting way off-topic; I've [taken it to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57417/discussion-between-kutulumike-and-dvk-on-ahch-to) and cleaned up my half.

Answer (score 15):

## [Ixrec](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/137186/ixrec)

[image]

Solidly decent human being, a true Mos regular, and a head so level that carpenters use it as a guide when they build stuff.  During my own brief stint as temporary room owner, he was a stronger voice of reason than I could ever be.  Also, he's just a really cool guy - the bee's knees.

Comment: ixrec is good. I wish he was on more.

Comment: Yeah, I should really stop forgetting to visit Mos.

Comment: Well make sure you do if you become RO! You have my support and I always enjoy chatting with you!

Answer (score 14):

I nominate nobody, since that [tends to not turn out well](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9674/19561), but **I propose to add more than one room owner if several nominees receive more or less the same score.**

Answer (score 12):

I nominate [Skooba](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/57310/skooba)

[image]

Very level headed and is a great mediator. I can't count how many times his was the voice of reason when I was active in the chat room. I think he would make a very good room owner for sure.

From what I can see Skooba is very active in chat and is well respected by other users. I hope Skooba does not mind me nominating him.

---

Edit by @Skooba

I would gladly accept the nomination to be considered as Room Owner. I have been active on Stack Exchange for about a year and a half now, and started my chatting activities a few months into that. I was instantly welcomed by the Mos regulars and quickly became one myself. I was also made the de facto Room Owner of the Game of Thrones Chat room (now known as the Quill and Tankard). It is not a very active room outside of when new GoT seasons are released, but there are a few of us who enjoy it year round.

I am located in UTC -5:00 (Eastern United States) and generally active during 7:00am to 5:00pm (UTC 12:00 to 22:00), Monday through Saturday.

I enjoy long walks off of short piers, Harry Potter, yelling obscenities in the rain, Game of Thrones, and scuba diving in my underwear.

<sub>Also, if there is any avatar confusion going with certain *other members* in chat, please see this [meta post](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9763/57310)....</sub>

Comment: Maybe someone else could post this for me. I suspect that me posting this will be the main reason for the down votes on this nomination.

Comment: I suspect unexplained downvotes hold very little power in the decision process, so don't worry about it much.

Comment: Yeah, I guess. I voted for you and a couple others here as well, as I think quite a few of the members nominated would be good hosts.

Comment: As always, don't worry about the down votes :).

Comment: @KyloRen - You do realize this is currently the answer with the *least* amount of downvotes, right?

Comment: @ibid, I am was just concerned that my reputation would affect this post and negatively influence Skooba.

Comment: @KyloRen - Pretty sure that having comments complaining about downvotes has a much higher change of attracting downvotes then the reputation of the poster does.

Comment: Skooba's another great choice.

Answer (score 3):

**MissMonicaE** seems qualified for the criteria.

[image]

- active participant — visits often enough, anyways
- intelligent
- hasn't gotten mired in any imbroglios, nor instigated any brouhahas, of which I am aware
- amiable demeanor but not obnoxious
  (that rules me out)
- will work to keep Mos Eisley's hallways clear of [excessive P.D.A.](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=36130431#36130431)
- we need more Ruritanians in public office!

Comment: I agree. Cheery and always polite.

Comment: [Also doesn't approve of excessive PDA in hallways](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=36130431#36130431)

Comment: Is imbroglio the word you want? Would brouhaha not be a better fit?

Comment: Thanks for the nomination! I am also unaware of being involved in any imbroglios, and I try to be amiable. :) I'm usually around on weekdays and sometimes on weekends, and I will happily work to keep Mos free of excessive hallway PDA.

Comment: @Valorum For the longest time, I thought that word was spelled _‘brewhaha’_ and referred to a ruckus in an alehouse or pub.

Answer (score -5):

I nominate [Valorum](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/20774/valorum).

Because no one can understand a crime better than a criminal himself (inspiration: When cyber laws first came into existence, governments hired cyber criminals themselves to enforce the laws) and everyone can agree that he is hyper active in chat and has proper manner to initiate a conversation and can understand what's going on with clarity. Giving him power can make him responsible for not to be part of crime.

I vote for a confidence.

---

EDIT (by @Valorum) -

I thank ILoveYou for his nomination, but **I decline**. Given my somewhat fraught relationship with the 'powers that be', I'm more interested in keeping under their radar for the next year or two.

Comment: by that logic @himarm ought to be appointed RO immediately.

Comment: @KutuluMike Benefits (of Himarm): We wouldn't have to have another thread like this. There'd be someone who wouldn't unreasonably flag/suspend people. 
He might not talk people down, but he would do the things we actually need an RO for.

Comment: @KutuluMike Counter: kick muting.

Comment: @Terriblefan -- An RO can freeze the room as well! :)

Comment: Why does this have delete vote?

Comment: @Skooba  Probably because he [declined](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/198?m=36694515#36694515) it.

Answer (score -12):

I nominate <s>Axelrod</s> [Axelord](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/175545/axelord).

[image]

- **Level-headed**: check.
- **Active**: [check](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/198/mos-eisley?id=198&tab=general&users=frequent).
- **Drama**: not that I've noticed during my 7 months on this site.
- <sub>**Capaldi avatar** (in chat): check.</sub>
- <sub>**Liked *Ghost Love Score* performed by Floor**: check.</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, I'll have to disagree with the third point. Axe has been involved in some drama - not a ton, but some - which also throws some suspicion over the first point as well.

Comment: @Mithrandir and I highlight the "last 7 months" part. In my opinion, if a user has not been involved in anything for more than half a year - that's a sign that we should leave past occurrences behind.

Comment: I'm confused, is this person's nick "Terriblefan" or "Axelord"? Who's "Alison Wonder-Land"?

Comment: OK, I understand now. "Terriblefan" is Axelord's SFF nick, and the other profile is probably wrongly linked.

Comment: @tobiasvl He uses different nicks on different SE sites, and changes his chat parent occasionally so that he can go from Axelrod to Terriblefan to Axelord in chat.

Comment: @tobiasvl :D oops :) My bad, had to get the flair template from Lit's elections, and type the ID by hand :D

Comment: @amaranth thanks, that was embarrassing :)

Comment: @tobiasvl [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h61UvcKeTdY)

Comment: @Mithrandir Oh come on. It's been a ton. And it would adversely affect my room ownership, because sooner or later someone with a blue name would get chat booted.

Comment: I was trying to avoid looking like I was bashing you, @Terriblefan.

Comment: Fortunately, moderators can't be kicked, @Terriblefan :)

Comment: @ArtOfCode Fortunate... *for them.*